# KSQL left join is not working

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am new to stackoverflow so let me know If I am anything wrong by posting this questions here.

I have tried finding the answers but couldn't find the KSQL JOIN related issues in the websites so I am posting this. I have tried different ways to run this query but I am consistently getting null pointer exceptions so posting it here.

I have 2 kafka avro topics deal & expense but data had alot of whitespaces to clear that I have created following topic and table with trimmed data. `DEAL_STREAM` and `EXPENSE_TABLE`

```
ksql> describe EXPENSE_TABLE;
```

Result:

```
Field      | Type
ROWTIME    | BIGINT (system)
ROWKEY     | VARCHAR(STRING) (system)
KSQL_COL_0 | VARCHAR(STRING)
KSQL_COL_1 | VARCHAR(STRING)
KSQL_COL_2 | VARCHAR(STRING)
```

And

```
ksql> describe deal_stream;
```

Result:

```
Field      | Type
ROWTIME    | BIGINT (system)
ROWKEY     | VARCHAR(STRING) (system)
KSQL_COL_0 | VARCHAR(STRING)
KSQL_COL_1 | VARCHAR(STRING)
KSQL_COL_2 | VARCHAR(STRING)
```

When I execute the following Query its giving me null pointer exception.
I tried following queries.

1:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM deal_expense_new AS SELECT td.KSQL_COL_0 , te.KSQL_COL_1 FROM deal_stream td LEFT JOIN expense_table te ON td.KSQL_COL_0 = te.KSQL_COL_0;
```

2:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM deal_expense_new AS SELECT td.KSQL_COL_0 AS KSQL_COL_0 , te.KSQL_COL_1 FROM deal_stream td LEFT JOIN expense_table te ON td.KSQL_COL_0 = te.KSQL_COL_0;
```

3:

```
CREATE STREAM deal_expense_trimmed AS SELECT td.KSQL_COL_0 AS KSQL_COL_0 , te.KSQL_COL_1 FROM deal_stream td LEFT JOIN expense_table te ON td.KSQL_COL_0 = te.KSQL_COL_0 where td.KSQL_COL_0 IS NOT NULL;
```

Error:

```
> Message Stream created and running ksql> Exception in thread
> "ksql_query_CSAS_DEAL_EXPENSE_NEW-01b2596a-3d2a-4d41-a823-0e345ec727fa-StreamThread-115"
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> io.confluent.ksql.structured.SchemaKStream.lambda$selectKey$3(SchemaKStream.java:248)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:159)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamTransformValues$KStreamTransformValuesProcessor.process(KStreamTransformValues.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:221)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:422)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:924)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:804)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:756)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:726)
> Exception in thread
> "ksql_query_CSAS_DEAL_EXPENSE_NEW-01b2596a-3d2a-4d41-a823-0e345ec727fa-StreamThread-116"
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> io.confluent.ksql.structured.SchemaKStream.lambda$selectKey$3(SchemaKStream.java:248)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:159)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamTransformValues$KStreamTransformValuesProcessor.process(KStreamTransformValues.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:221)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:422)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:924)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:804)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:756)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:726)
> Exception in thread
> "ksql_query_CSAS_DEAL_EXPENSE_NEW-01b2596a-3d2a-4d41-a823-0e345ec727fa-StreamThread-113"
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> io.confluent.ksql.structured.SchemaKStream.lambda$selectKey$3(SchemaKStream.java:248)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:159)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamTransformValues$KStreamTransformValuesProcessor.process(KStreamTransformValues.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:221)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:422)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:924)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:804)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:756)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:726)
> Exception in thread
> "ksql_query_CSAS_DEAL_EXPENSE_NEW-01b2596a-3d2a-4d41-a823-0e345ec727fa-StreamThread-114"
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> io.confluent.ksql.structured.SchemaKStream.lambda$selectKey$3(SchemaKStream.java:248)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:159)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$2.apply(KStreamImpl.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamTransformValues$KStreamTransformValuesProcessor.process(KStreamTransformValues.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.forward(AbstractProcessorContext.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:221)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:422)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:924)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:804)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:756)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:726)
```

Comment: Does it work if you just run the `SELECT` (and not the `CREATE STREAM` prefix)?

Comment: Can you add your `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE STREAM` statements, and a sample of the data from each underlying topic?

Comment: Given that you're getting an exception, you may be better logging this as an issue on the KSQL github repository:  https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new - if this is user error (and it's not clear) then at least the error should be nicer. And if it's a bug, then it needs fixing :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt It doesn't work for select as well. I tried filtering the fields with NULL & empty value then also it's not working. I am using the ksql 0.5 release of Feb 2018

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have already added the issue. https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/968#issuecomment-373779244

Comment: It seems there is some issue with the AVRO schema. https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/894  but my key schema is String. I have tried the solution which stopped null pointer but still join is not working.

Answer (score 6):

This bug should be fixed in the latest master. The fix will be included in the next monthly release. Here's the github issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/521

Comment: Hi Rohan, I am using Feb 2018 release which is ksql 0.5 & the link you shared was resolved in December 2017 so I think its already accommodated in the release I am using.